# Javascript - Streaming a recorded audio as microphone input

Tags: javascript, audio, testim.io

I'm working on automated tests through Testim. Part of my test requires playing/streaming a recorded audio through the microphone so the other side hears it. This is not supported in Testim tool, however I'm wondering if I can perform the same action through javascript as it supports using custom scripts. I can't use an external software such as VB-Audio Virtual Cable, I need something directly from JS. Any ideas if it's technically possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Testim allows chrome browser to [mock](https://help.testim.io/docs/allow-chrome-browser-to-use-microphone) microphone. To enable the microphone use

```
--chrome-extra-args with the value "use-fake-device-for-media-stream"
```